# java.io.FileNotFoundException: The requested resource is not available

Tags: java

I need your help in finding the solution to the error which I am getting as I have tried my level best to solve the error .

The error(which is showing in Console) is :

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [servlet.RegisterServlet] in
>   context with path [/Company_Mailer_System] threw exception
>   **java.io.FileNotFoundException:** The requested resource [/Company_Mailer_System/header.html] is not available   at
>   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.serveResource(DefaultServlet.java:797)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:454)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.doPost(DefaultServlet.java:547)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet.service(DefaultServlet.java:434)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
>     at servlet.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:24)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

My code is as follows :

```
package servlet;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/RegisterServlet")

public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
  response) throws ServletException, IOException
 {
     response.setContentType("text/html");
     PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

    request.getRequestDispatcher("header.html").include(request, 
    response);      
    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    String password=request.getParameter("password");
    String email=request.getParameter("email");
    String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
    String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
    String addressLine=request.getParameter("addressLine");
    String city=request.getParameter("city");
    String state=request.getParameter("state");
    String country=request.getParameter("country");
    String contact=request.getParameter("contact");


    int status=dao.RegisterDao.save(name, email+"@cmailer.com", password, gender, dob, addressLine, city, state, country, contact);
    if(status>0)
    {
        out.print("<p>You are successfully registered!</p>");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.html").include(request, response);
    }
    else
        out.print("<p>You are successfully not registered!</p>");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("footer.html").include(request, response);     
}}
```

The header.html file is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.inputform{float:left;
width:400px;border:1px solid pink;border-radius:10px;padding:10px;
}
.inputform table tr td input,textarea,select{width:200px;}
#gender1,#gender2{width:10px;}
#submit{margin-left:100px;width:100px;} 
#reset{width:100px;}
.design{background-color:red;color:white;padding-left:100px;}
</style>
<body>
<!-- header -->
<h2>Company Mailer</h2>
<h3 style="background-color:red;color:red;">c</h3>
<!-- body -->
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: The stack trace say it can't find your `header.html` file. Make sure the html file in the correct path?

Comment: @ST.Kee Yes, It is in correct path .The file is in Web Content.